# Subgurim GDirection not displaying on web page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am using subgurim on my webpage and I am trying to get the directions to populate.  I have the markers properly being displayed.  I am not in the process of adding the directions, but I am not seeing why they are not being displayed.

Below is the web page:

```
<%@ register assembly="GMaps" namespace="Subgurim.Controles" tagprefix="cc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
<table align="center" width="80%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" width="10%">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDirectionsFrom" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Drive From:" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDirectionsFrom" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox" Width="100px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Visible="false" AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" width="20%" colspan="3">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDirectionsTo" runat="server" CssClass="Label" Text="Drive To:" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDirectionsTo" runat="server" CssClass="Textbox" Width="100px" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Visible="false" AutoPostBack="True">
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" colspan="4" width="40%">
        <input type="button" id="bt_Go" runat="server" value="Get Directions" onserverclick="GetDirections" class="CmdButton" visible="False" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" valign="top" width="10%">
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" width="20%" colspan="3">
    </td>
    <td align="left" valign="top" colspan="4" width="40%">
        <asp:Label ID="txtMapMsg"
            runat="server"
            Text="txtMapMsg"
            CssClass="Msgbox"
            Width="80%"
            Visible="False"
            BackColor="#F7B432"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" colspan="4" width="60%">
        <asp:TextBox ID="tb_fromPoint" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="tb_fromPointResource1"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tb_endPoint" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="tb_endPointResource1"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" Key="googlemaps.subgurim.net" CommercialKey="googlemaps.subgurim.net_Commercial" enableServerEvents="true" />
        <div id="div_directions"></div>
    </td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" colspan="4" width="40%">            
    </td>
</tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the code for creating the directions

```
Protected Sub GetDirections()
    Dim NavcareDirection As New GDirection()
    Dim sItemNbr As String

    txtMapMsg.Visible = False
    txtMapMsg.Text = ""

    If ddlDirectionsFrom.SelectedItem.Value = "0" Then
        txtMapMsg.Text = "You must select a From to get directions"
        txtMapMsg.Visible = True
        txtOtherStart.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ddlDirectionsTo.SelectedItem.Value = "0" Then
        txtMapMsg.Text = "You must select a TO to get directions"
        txtMapMsg.Visible = True
        txtOtherStart.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    sItemNbr = ddlDirectionsFrom.SelectedItem.Value

    tb_fromPoint.Visible = True
    tb_endPoint.Visible = True


    NavcareDirection = New GDirection()
    NavcareDirection.autoGenerate = False
    NavcareDirection.buttonElementId = "bt_Go"
    NavcareDirection.fromElementId = tb_fromPoint.ClientID
    NavcareDirection.toElementId = tb_endPoint.ClientID
    NavcareDirection.divElementId = "div_directions"
    NavcareDirection.clearMap = True

    NavcareDirection.errorMessage = "Directions Error"

    GMap1.Add(NavcareDirection)
End Sub
```

I am not getting any error and no directions.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I have come back and found what I was doing wrong.

```
NavcareDirection = New GDirection()
NavcareDirection.autoGenerate = False
NavcareDirection.buttonElementId = "bt_Go"
NavcareDirection.fromElementId = tb_fromPoint.ClientID
NavcareDirection.toElementId = tb_endPoint.ClientID
NavcareDirection.divElementId = "div_directions"
NavcareDirection.clearMap = True

NavcareDirection.errorMessage = "Directions Error"

GMap1.Add(NavcareDirection)
```

Once there, I finally received error messages, but I am not sure why I am getting them.  I will place that into a new question.